# не отправляется Notification

Tags: android, android-notification, pendingintent

Есть сервис, по расписанию качает новости, после загрузки отправляет уведомление - `Notification`. В последнее время начал замечать что сервис отрабатывает, однако уведомление не отправляет. Повесил логи в аналитику, метод отправки сообщения вызывается - однако сообщение не доходит (Причем может через раз отправлять, может день не отправлять а потом день все нормально). Что может быть не так, код прилагается.

```
public void sendMessage(int countNews){
    Resources resources = getResources();
    Intent i = NewsListActivity.newIntent(this);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, i, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setTicker(resources.getString(R.string.get_new_news))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_logo)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setNumber(countNews)
            .setContentTitle(resources.getString(R.string.get_new_news))
            .setContentText(resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.news_plurals, countNews, countNews))
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Не может это быть из-за того что `PendingIntent` у `Notification` по `requestCode` совпадает с `PendingIntent` сервиса - последний для периодического запуска через `AlarmManager`.

чтобы не пересекались `ID` у `PendingIntent` исправил код:

```
public void sendMessage(int countNews){
    Resources resources = getResources();
    Intent i = NewsListActivity.newIntent(this);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, NOTIFICATION_INTENT_ID, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setTicker(resources.getString(R.string.get_new_news))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_logo)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setNumber(countNews)
            .setContentTitle(resources.getString(R.string.get_new_news))
            .setContentText(resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.news_plurals, countNews, countNews))
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

сутки сообщения отправлялись отлично, все работало, ночью новости скачались - сообщения нет, днем еще подгрузились - опять сообщение не пришло. Как будто аппарат очень крепко "уснул" и не принимает уведомления...
Причем на втором аппарате с Android 5.1 уведомления приходят - на Android 6.0 вышеописанная картина.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С 6 андроида из-за Doze для точных уведомлений следует использовать методы:

If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use **setAndAllowWhileIdle()** or **setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()**.
 https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: и все бы замечательно - однако как я понял, это для разового вызова, а для повторяющихся методов нет.

Comment: Можно ловить событие уведомления в broadcast, и при срабатывании последнего твоего уведомления - регистрировать новое

Comment: вечером попробую причепиться в слегка другое место - у меня сервис запускает загрузку новостей в многопоточном режиме, причем запуск происходит через паттерн наблюдатель и в нем по окончанию вызывается либо отправка сообщений, либо отмена (если нет новостей) - вот думаю в эти два метода прицепить перезапуск сервиса в `AlarmManager`

Comment: Что бы все время не держать сервис можно в ресивере его запускать. Допустим при старте приложения запустил сервис - он завел первый Alarm, далее в ресивере когда уведомление придет - запустить сервис снова. Так же для перезапуска уведомлений при включении телефона тоже можно ловить броадкаст на включение... правда это будет работать до андроид О

Comment: у меня сервис через `AlarmManager` стартует - он не висит постоянно.

Comment: методы которые вы описали работают, причем они не "будят" устройство, а помещают уведомление в какую-то очередь, стоит включить - сразу прилетают уведомления.

Answer (score 1):

Очень похоже, что проблема из-за режима [Doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) (как раз появился в 6.0).

Примерно происходит так:

- Телефон лежит неподвижно без подзарядки
- Система переходит в режим Doze
- Отрабатывает сервис, но Doze игнорирует wake lock и нотификация не срабатывает. То есть в окошко, которое дает для работы Doze сервис успевает отработать, а все дальше уже нет (примерно так, не видя весь код сложно сказать точнее).

Проверить можно внеся приложение в "белый список" (Настройки -> Батарея -> меню -> Экономия зараяда батареи -> все приложения -> клик и выбрать не экономить батарею) и проверив повторяется ли описанное в вопросе поведение.

Comment: Проверим - вчера накопал эту же информацию, на англоязычном ресурсе. Пара дней на тестирование)